# Plotting a spreadsheet in LabVIEW

Tags: excel, plot, graph, spreadsheet, labview

i am having troubles in plotting an XY graphic in LabVEW.

I know that we have a VI that can plot XY graphs, however i want to plot the graph of an excel table that was saved as TXT file.

For this, i tried to use Read From Spreadsheet VI, with this i can read the tables, but i don't know why, i can not plot the graph in the XY graphic VI.

I tried to create two spreadsheets with the values for X and for Y and read it with two Read From Spreadsheet VI, so i could provide the values for the XY graph VI, but it did not work as well.

What is happening is that the XY graph only plot the first number of the Spreadsheet, it does not plot all the spreadsheet numbers.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpGmR.png)

Comment: It is possible to do with Read From Spreadsheet VI. using XY graph is the best option as well. Try and everything will work. Your question is not a specific question. This is "please help" question which is not accepted in this website. Please consider removing your question. Or asking the specific one.

Comment: No, it is a specific question. How to import spreadsheet and plot its graphic using LabVIEW. Because XY graphics and Read From Spreadsheet VI does not work for this propose once the XY graph is not recognizing the values in the spreadsheet. Also, the question has its relevance since there is no where to find the answer for this question. If it were that simple i would not be here asking, so if you are not interested in contributing, do not loose your time writing.

Comment: What if I show you it is simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the "Convert to Dynamic Data2" vi is not configured properly.
Try double clicking it and selecting as input data type "2D array of scalars - columns are channels".
I've quickly tested it and it's working